# Keeping parent-child relationships when using Python's ElementTree .iter()

Tags: python, relationship, parent, elementtree

I have the following markup:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
    <d>
    <e>
  </b>
  <f>
    <g>
  </f>
</a>
```

using the ElementTree function **.iter()** I get something like:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

I need to find a way too keep the relationships between parent and child, example, I want to know that "f" parent is "a". The only way I can think as of now is every time I find a parent node: **len(list(elem)) > 0**, I add that node to a list and keep track of the current "level" of the node to make that relation. I don't find that solution very elegant and I'm sure there is an easier solution for this, unfortunately I wasn't able to find it yet :/, I hope someone can shed some light upon me :D

ps. Before someone comments "use the search before you ask", I already read every post that is, in some way, related to what I'm trying to do, like:

- [Keep track of parent elements using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566292/keep-track-of-parent-elements-using-elementtree)
- [Iterating multiple (parent,child) nodes using Python ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720476/iterating-multiple-parent-child-nodes-using-python-elementtree)

It happens they are very use case specific and did not quite help me, or atleast I didn't find a way to connect their solution to mine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use dictionaries? Parent is key, children are value. Works if children can only have one parent, which should be true in XML.

Comment: Using my markup as example, in my case I can have <c> appearing in <b> and <f>, not often, but it can happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary, which is more favorable for tree-like structures. The goal is for the key of a dictionary to be a parent, the values are a list of children. Here's how you can do it:

```
def get_children(parent):
    return [child for child in parent]

def get_parent_children_mapping(tree):
    return {parent: get_children(parent) for parent in tree.iter()}
```

Example usage would be:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_children(parent):
    return [child for child in parent]

def get_parent_children_mapping(tree):
    return { parent: get_children(parent) for parent in tree.iter() }

if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = """
    <a>
      <b>
        <c>Hello</c>
        <d>World</d>
        <e>Goodbye</e>
      </b>
      <f>
        <g>Hmmm...</g>
        <c>Hello</c>
      </f>
    </a>
    """

    tree = ET.fromstring(s)

    for parent, children in get_parent_children_mapping(tree).items():
        if children:
            print("{0} -> {1}".format(parent, children))
```

You'll find the root element is omitted -- this is because it obviously has no parents, but its children are all that are returned from `get_parent_children_mapping` on the entire tree.

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/E4Dk). Just make sure your XML is valid.

Comment: What happens if a node can appear duplicated? This can happen on childs and parents (in my case)

Comment: If there's nesting, you'll have to play with recursion. Your example didn't have it, so I didn't add it.

Comment: I tested on my code and the the child-parent relationships appear all scrambled. I can't have that on my code because I need the nodes to be ordered (depth-first style), which was one of the reasons that, at first, I thought the list format was cool.

Comment: @VitorMexia Look at [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).